# OpenGL GL_BLEND

Tags: c++, opengl, transparency

I would like to draw 16 x 16 squares of texture_water with increasing transparency along the i-Axis. Unfortunatly all 16x16 squares are blended with the alpha value that is set when `glColor4f` is first called (in this case 0). Moving the `glBegin(GL_QUADS);` inside the loop did not help. What am I doing wrong?

```
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_DST_ALPHA);        
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_water);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    for (UINT i = 0; i < numCells; i++) {
        for (UINT l = 0; l < numCells; l++)  {              
            float h = ((float)(i) / 16);
            glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, h);
            glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(sc*i, sc*l, 0.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(sc*i, sc*(l + 1), 0.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(sc*(i + 1), sc*(l + 1), 0.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(sc*(i + 1), sc*l, 0.0f);                             
        }
    }
    glEnd();
```

Comment: Can you write down the blending equation you'd like to implement? Something like `rgb_(i-1) = Σ_i t_rgb · … and so on`. I think your choice of blending function may throw you off.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have a base texture and would like to blend the texture_water with it. `glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0f)` should mean that the result is 100% base texture and no water texture and `glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0f)` should result in only showing the water texture. I also tried `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE)` but that did not do produce the wanted results either.

Comment: For what you want the blend function would be `dst = src.alpha * src + (1 - src.alpha) * dst`. The OpenGL call to set this up would be `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`. This function is also known as the *mix* function.

Comment: Thank you very much. 
Unfortunatly the second part of the problem namely that all quads are blended the same way still remains.

Comment: @user3049681: There are many possibilities that could go wrong. One thing that comes to mind is the `TEXTURE_ENV_MODE` you set, since you might overwrite your per-vertex alpha component with the value from the texture if you set the wrong one. Another thing could be that `GL_LIGHTING` is enabled, which will totally override the color attribute.

Comment: Just so you know, a lot of framebuffers do not even store an alpha channel. Destination alpha (`GL_DST_ALPHA`) is the alpha value stored in the framebuffer, it is rarely what you want when trying to do alpha blending.

Comment: Thanks. I did some reading into the mentioned TEXTURE_ENV_MODE and multi texturing and it's obviously not as easy and straight forward as I thought. I have to read up on the topic before I can implement what I wanted.